# CIL instructions unexpected return value

Tags: oop, stack, clr, cil, reflection.emit

I am trying to create il-instructions manually for learning purposes, but have run into a small problem.

I have a simple structure with an interface: "MyInterface" with a single method: "Handle", a class called "AddTwo" which implements "MyInterface" and a "Program" class with an entrymethod. The il-dump looks like this:

```
.class interface public abstract auto ansi MyInterface<TInput,TOutput>
{
  .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
          instance !TOutput  Handle(!TInput A_1) cil managed
  {
  } // end of method MyInterface::Handle

} // end of class MyInterface

.class public auto ansi plusTwo
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
       implements class MyInterface<int32,int32>
{
  .method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
          instance int32  Handle(int32 x) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       13 (0xd)
    .maxstack  2
    IL_0000:  ldarg      0
    IL_0004:  nop
    IL_0005:  nop
    IL_0006:  ldc.i4     0x2
    IL_000b:  add
    IL_000c:  ret
  } // end of method plusTwo::Handle
 } // end of class plusTwo

.class public auto ansi Program
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public static int32  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       34 (0x22)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (int32 V_0)
    IL_0000:  newobj     instance void plusTwo::.ctor()
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4     0xa
    IL_000a:  callvirt   instance !1 class MyInterface<int32,int32>::Handle(!0)
    IL_000f:  stloc      V_0
    IL_0013:  nop
    IL_0014:  nop
    IL_0015:  ldloc      V_0
    IL_0019:  nop
    IL_001a:  nop
    IL_001b:  ldc.i4     0x5
    IL_0020:  add
    IL_0021:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main
} // end of class Program
```

In the above I expect the output to be: 17, but instead I get a random high integer that changes with each test. It looks like a memory address or something. Can someone tell, by looking at the generated IL above, what the problem might be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ldarg 0 produces the *this* pointer for an instance method.  Make it a static method or use ldarg 1.  Otherwise something you can always discover by writing the code in C# first and looking at the IL that the compiler generates.

Comment: @HansPassant : That did the trick, thank you very much. You should post this as the answer.